# How to map JSON data to table/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I get a json data as follows :

```
{
    "encoding_version" : 1,
    "root" : {
        "_type" : lookup_config_data",
        "Class" : ".key.LookData",
        "Tbl" : {
            "_type" : "lookup_table",
            "Class" : ".key.LookupTable",
            "Lhs" : { "_type" : "array<variant>", "_data" : [
                ".key.test1",
                ".key.test2",
                ".key.test3",
                ".key.test4",
                ".key.test5"                

            ] },
            "Groups" : { "_type" : "array<array<key>>", "_data" : [
                { "_type" : "array<key>", "_data" : [
                    ".key.data1",
                    ".key.data12"
                ] },
                { "_type" : "array<key>", "_data" : [
                    ".key.data2"
                ] },
                { "_type" : "array<key>", "_data" : [
                    ".key.data3"
                ] },
                { "_type" : "array<key>", "_data" : [
                    ".key.data4"
                ] },
                { "_type" : "array<key>", "_data" : [
                    ".key.data5"
                ] }


            ] }
        }
    }
}
```

is there is way to map as follows :

test1 -> data1,data12

test2 -> data2

test3 -> data3

test4 -> data4

test5 -> data5

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: its unclear what you want to achieve..."is there is way to map as follows :
test1 -> data1,data12" what does this mean? please be clear and also include desired outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the above data has a pre-defined schema. So every grammar of the schema definition need to be taken care of. But as a starting point, you can the below code.

```js
var obj = {
  "encoding_version" : 1,
  "root" : {
      "_type" : "lookup_config_data",
      "Class" : ".key.LookData",
      "Tbl" : {
          "_type" : "lookup_table",
          "Class" : ".key.LookupTable",
          "Lhs" : { "_type" : "array<variant>", "_data" : [
              ".key.test1",
              ".key.test2",
              ".key.test3",
              ".key.test4",
              ".key.test5"                

          ] },
          "Groups" : { "_type" : "array<array<key>>", "_data" : [
              { "_type" : "array<key>", "_data" : [
                  ".key.data1",
                  ".key.data12"
              ] },
              { "_type" : "array<key>", "_data" : [
                  ".key.data2"
              ] },
              { "_type" : "array<key>", "_data" : [
                  ".key.data3"
              ] },
              { "_type" : "array<key>", "_data" : [
                  ".key.data4"
              ] },
              { "_type" : "array<key>", "_data" : [
                  ".key.data5"
              ] }


          ] }
      }
  }
};

var newObj = {};
var keys = obj.root.Tbl.Lhs._data;
var values = obj.root.Tbl.Groups._data;

if (keys.length == values.length){
  keys.forEach((e,i)=>{
    newObj[extractData(e)] = values[i]._data.map(v=>extractData(v));
  })
}

function extractData(raw){
  return raw.split('.')[2];
}
console.log(newObj);
```

The `newObj` will be a map of `Lhs` keys to `Groups` values.